# Azure Synapse Pool (formaly DWH) ownership chaining problem

Tags: sql-server

This is running on a Synapze dedicated pool, formally Azure Data Warehouse...

I'm having these objects as result from this query

```
SELECT 
              s.name + '.' + o.name AS ObjectName
            , COALESCE(p.name, p2.name) AS OwnerName
            , o.type

  FROM sys.all_objects o
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals p 
             ON o.principal_id = p.principal_id

  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas s 
                ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id

  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals p2 
                ON s.principal_id = p2.principal_id

  WHERE      s.name NOT IN ('sys', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
           and o.name like '%waterm%'
```

Results are

| ObjectName | OwnerName | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dbo.ADF_Set_WaterMark | dbo | P |
| dbo.ADF_Watermark | dbo | U |
| dbo.Reset_Watermarks | dbo | P |
| rdv_70_001.Watermarks | dbo | V |

This statement has been issued

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[Reset_Watermarks] TO [ot-linkworkx]
GO
```

But when I execute as ot-linkworkx I'm still getting this error.

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'ADF_Watermark', database 'syndpeu2dtaedw9', schema 'dbo'.
> The DELETE permission was denied on the object 'ADF_Watermark', database 'syndpeu2dtaedw9', schema 'dbo'.
>
> Completion time: 2023-05-25T15:06:50.8775877+02:00

This should not happen I thought ....

Any ideas ?

Comment: do you use dynamic sql to manipulate adf_watermark?

Comment: No, just some if then delete, depeding on the parameter passed.